# Transpose a datatable column to row form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying to transpose a datatable in the way displayed [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTuIU.png) .

Would you please help me solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you Google this?  Seems pretty straightforward.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         GridReport.DataSource = <your datatable>;
         // This is the table I shown in Figure 1.1

         GridReport.DataBind();

         // Your other codes here (if any)
     }
}

protected void btnTransposeReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataTable inputTable = <your datatable>;
     // Table shown in Figure 1.1

     DataTable transposedTable = GenerateTransposedTable(inputTable);

     GridReport.DataSource = transposedTable;
     // Table shown in Figure 1.2

     GridReport.DataBind();
}

private DataTable GenerateTransposedTable(DataTable inputTable)
{
     DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

     // Add columns by looping rows

     // Header row's first column is same as in inputTable
     outputTable.Columns.Add(inputTable.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());

     // Header row's second column onwards, 'inputTable's first column taken
     foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
     {
         string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
         outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
     }

     // Add rows by looping columns        
     for (int rCount = 1; rCount <= inputTable.Columns.Count - 1; rCount++)
     {
         DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();

         // First column is inputTable's Header row's second column
         newRow[0] = inputTable.Columns[rCount].ColumnName.ToString();
         for (int cCount = 0; cCount <= inputTable.Rows.Count - 1; cCount++)
         {
             string colValue = inputTable.Rows[cCount][rCount].ToString();
             newRow[cCount + 1] = colValue;
         }
         outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
     }

     return outputTable;
}
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C